# Javscript Performance of Objects vs Maps for Contest Problems

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary, object

I used memoization to try and improve performance for a recursive algorithm. I would expect about the same performance for Objects and Maps in Javascript (O(1) for reads and writes).

Looking at other StackOverflow posts, they say performance may differ 2x or 3x performance depending on the implementation/browser, however, I am seeing a ~40x performance difference between the Objects vs Maps implementation algorithm.

The performance for the object implementation is ~8000ms on LeetCode (faster than only 5% of js solutions and slower than not using memoization).

While the map implementation performace is ~184ms on LeetCode (faster than 70% of js solutions).

Below is my code. Exact same solution, object solution is uncommented while map solution is commented out.

Does my code have a big mistake for the object memoization implementation that is making it much slower? Or is this a LeetCode Map vs Object implementation difference?

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} S
 * @return {number}
 */


var findTargetSumWays = function(nums, S) {
    //let memo=new Map(); 
    let memo={};
    return helper(0,S);

    function helper(numsPointer,S){
        let numWays=0;
        if(numsPointer==nums.length&&S===0){return 1;} //base case. All nums in array used and Sum matches
        if(numsPointer==nums.length){return 0;} //all nums in array used
        //if(memo.has(numsPointer+":"+S)){return memo.get(numsPointer+":"+S);}
        if(memo[numsPointer+":"+S]){return memo[numsPointer+":"+S];}

        let curr=nums[numsPointer];

        numWays+=helper(numsPointer+1,S+curr);
        numWays+=helper(numsPointer+1,S-curr);
        //memo.set(numsPointer+":"+S,numWays); //store results
        memo[numsPointer+":"+S]=numWays;
        return numWays;
    }//helper


};
```

Problem from LeetCode is:

> You are given a list of non-negative integers, a1, a2, ..., an, and a target, S. Now you have 2 symbols + and -. For each integer, you should choose one from + and - as its new symbol.
>   Find out how many ways to assign symbols to make sum of integers equal to target S.

Correct solution when using both Maps and Objects for memoization, but huge performance difference. Using Objects for memoization is actually causing performance losses.

Thank you!

Comment: This is likely a better question for CodeReview instead of StackOverflow

Comment: does it work ???

Comment: Both the Map solution and the Object solution work. The map solution is about 40x faster than the object solution though, while I would expect similar performance.

Comment: IIRC maps are explicitly optimized for adding/removing objects, and objects do additional work for inheritance and key mapping. Maps have been faster than objects for some time.